# Text container with border and fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css, text, border

I have searched everywhere and I can not find the way to do what I show in the image. Could someone give me an idea? Sorry my English ... google translate for me :-p

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could make a block with a border and then put a white block over the border in order to break the border.

Comment: Send your code than we can help you. This is very simple.

Comment: Ty Sonia...

HTML CODE:

<div class="cuadro">
 <span><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x fa-border" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  Proin elementum justo eget nisi semper sodales.
</div>

CSS CODE:

.cuadro {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.fa-border {
  padding: .2em .25em .15em;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  border-radius: .1em;
}

Comment: Finally i did !!!


HTML CODE:

<div class="cuadro">
 <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x half-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  Proin elementum justo eget nisi semper sodales.
</div>

CSS CODE:

.cuadro {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.half-circle {
 margin-top: -50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 75px;
 border-top-left-radius: 110px;
 border-top-right-radius: 110px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-bottom: 0;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

Ty all for support.